# Is there a way to uses Places API to only return Gyms?

Tags: google-places-api

I'm currently using the Places Nearby API to return gyms given geocoordinates, but its returning personal trainers too. I'm guessing that's a subtype of Gym so I want to know if I can return only Gym Chains/Actual Gyms instead without programming a filter or guess-checking with different keywords?

Comment: Have you tried something on your own? I know this is a special question that needs a special answer, but I can only lead you to read the API documentation and research and try it on your own. I would try to look for characteristics what an personal trainer makes out and filter them out, if the Places API does not have it on it own.

Comment: Only `gym` is supported, the API has no supported subtypes for it so you'd indeed need to implement a filter yourself.